# How to record desktop screen in angular 2+ application

Tags: angular, angular6, screen-recording

I need to share desktop screen via `Angular 6`. I have searched for suitable package to implement this feature but couldn't found it.

Actually I found many packages like [RecordRTC](https://recordrtc.org/CanvasRecorder.html), [Aperture](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aperture), [screen-capture-recorder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/screen-capture-recorder) and some others. Some of them were incompatible, some were poorly documented and non-availability of code-intellisense.

Please tell me the most compatible and well documented package that I can use with `Angular 6`. Platform I am working on is `Windows`

Comment: Do you mean to share/record exactly DESKTOP? or do you mean to share/record activity in the website page?

Angular works only within the browser.

Comment: I want to record the DESKTOP, not just browser/website.

Comment: If angular works in a browser only then what should be done to record the DESKTOP.

Comment: @WasiF a standalone client.

Comment: @trichetriche can you please elaborate, what you want to say? Sorry, I couldn't understand

Comment: A standalone client is a software that you have to install with the windows Wizard or Linux's APT. It needs permissions on your computer : Angular only has permissions in your browser tab.

Comment: @trichetriche can you provide me a link to study it deeply so that I can clearly understand and implement

Comment: Is there any `node` package that can do this? because angular is limited in this case

Comment: No I can't. Standalones clients can be made with any language, you'll have to find it yourself (besides, I have never tried screen recording myself). I don't know if Node offers that either, but I wouldn't use Node to make it. Maybe Java or C#, which have been used in the past for that kind of software ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally find some working solution...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-screen',
  template: `<video #video autoplay style="width:360px;"></video>`
})
export class ScreenComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.startRecording()
  }

  async startRecording() {
    // navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true })
    // or
    // navigator.getDisplayMedia({ video: true })

    let stream = await navigator.getDisplayMedia({ video: true })
    console.log(stream)
    this.videoElement.srcObject = stream
  }


  @ViewChild('video') videoElementRef: ElementRef
  get videoElement(): HTMLVideoElement {
    return this.videoElementRef.nativeElement
  }

}
```

As this feature is in experimental phase, so enable `Experimental Web Platform features` flag to record the user screen. To enable, follow this below image

[image]

> Note: It is tested on `chrome v71.x.x`, make sure your browser is up to date.
> Also note that, this will not work in `Electron` app as someone down voted me it might be possible that he/she tried to use this in `Electron` app.
> You have to use this solution in browser specific application but not in `Electron` right now.

Comment: Is it working? I just wonder how do you get screen view of user.

Comment: This is the code that gives you the stream of a user screen. `let stream = await navigator.getDisplayMedia({ video: true })`

Comment: You facing issue in screen capturing?

Comment: Nope i just wonder how do you get screen view. I mean how do you see clients screen in your browser.

Comment: Create this component and watch how it works. It works like a charm. It's a new feature so add flag to your browser and it'll work for you

Comment: @WasiF When I write getDisplayMedia in Visual Studio Code it tells me it does not exist for type Navigator.  Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: @Spitz use `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true })`. You can check answer, I have updated.